# Setting up Heroku addons as a student with no credit card

Tags: python, django, heroku, credit-card, cloudinary

I am a student and I don't have a credit card and I am using Heroku to deploy my Django application. Files uploaded onto Heroku are not saved so I intended to use Cloudinary to store media files uploaded via my Django app.

Is there no other way to set up Cloudinary to work on Heroku without using the addon which requires verifying my account with credit card info?

I have tried Googling but all the results I found are people who requires more than 5 apps running and suggested solution was to create multiple accounts, so I am kind of at a loss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sign up for Cloudinary for free on their [site](https://cloudinary.com/users/register/free) without having to input credit card info.

Afterward, you will need to save the `CLOUDINARY_URL` as an environment variable in your Heroku app, and you should be able to access Cloudinary's APIs.

Comment: Oh wow, I guess this is why you should always try things first before asking. Hard habit to break. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a thing for MySql too ???